# Working Remotely in Canada and get paid to a Canadian Bank

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada, work-permit

So under the Canadian law it is legal to work remotely in Canada while on Visitor Visa, the question I have is about one clause they have in the following rule, can I get paid from my foreign employer to a Canadian bank. Basically have my employer transfer to my Canadian bank account.

[This link](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/what-is-work.html) indicates on the subject of what isn't considered work,

> long distance (by telephone or Internet) work done by a temporary
> resident whose employer is outside Canada and who is remunerated from
> outside Canada;

.. which I take as "as long as you get paid to a non-Canadian bank account it's fine since it won't be considered work".

Does anyone have any experience with such scenarios? It would great if I can get confirmation for similar situations.

Comment: How do you have a Canadian bank account with a visitor visa?  I don't know about Canada specifically, but it does seem that in most countries you need to be a resident, or to have some other reason such as maintaining a part-time residence, in order to be able to open a personal bank account.

Comment: Also, "remunerated from a non-Canadian bank account" is a condition on the _source_ of the money, not its _destination._  In other words, that text does not mean "as long as you get paid to a non-Canadian bank account it's fine since it won't be considered work."

Comment: @phoog thank you for your comments, yes some banks actually allows you to open a bank account as a Visitor, your passport would be used in that case as the identity.

Comment: @phoog At least a decade ago it was possible at all major banks to open account without necessarily a proof of residence. But nowadays it's becoming more difficult but I believe still possible.

Comment: For visitors as long as it is *from* a foreign source it is ok. But tax-wise there may be other implications.